# How to link a library to a smart contract using Foundry

Tags: solidity, library, foundry

I am using Foundry https://book.getfoundry.sh/ and wanted to deploy a library having external methods and link it to a contract before deploying it.

Can someone share any docs or a simple example of doing it

Answer (score 1):

It looks possible: https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-build?highlight=link#linker-options

Seems you have to deploy library first, then specify the details. I can't find a worked example, though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Foundry does not have specific documentation about linking a library to a Smart Contract. However, you may try looking into deploying your library separately from the contract and then calling the library functions from within the contract. The Foundry SDK provides the ability to deploy libraries separately from contracts, as well as the ability to call functions from other contracts. You can also consider using a tool like truffle, which supports linking external libraries.